# Chain rule of partial differentiation (Cartesian to Polar)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

> I am actually doing a question that involves the conversion of cartesian to polar coordinates and I am stuck at a partial derivative part.

> Given $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\phi = \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$, I am finding partial derivative with respect to $y$.

According to my teacher's working:

$(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y})_x = (\frac{\partial \tan \phi}{\partial y})_x \frac{d\phi}{d\tan \phi} = \frac{1}{x} \cos^2 \phi$

What is actually going on here? I could not understand it. I understand that the partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $y$ involves only differentiating the $y$ component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the hidden steps your teacher did :
$$
\begin{array}{rclll}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{\partial(\tan\phi)}{\partial(\tan\phi)}\cdot\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{\partial(\tan\phi)}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial(\tan\phi)}  \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{\partial (y/x)}{\partial y}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial(\tan\phi)}{\partial\phi}\right)^{-1} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{x}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}\right)^{-1} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{\cos^2\phi}{x}
\end{array}
$$

Alternatively, you can prove this result by differentiating directly the relation $\tan\phi = \frac{y}{x}$ with respect to $y$, i.e. $\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Finally, it is to be noticed that all this circumvention is made to avoid to compute the derivative of $\arctan$, but its expression wouldn't be that difficult to handle, knowing that $\arctan'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.